# Labeling and manipulating each stack in a bar stack chart

Tags: python, plotly, bokeh

I am trying to create waterfall charts using different alternatives to `plotly`'s waterfall function due to it not being able to cope with stacked charts. So I decided to create bar charts and hide the base layers to get what I want. This code below gets what I want visually but I need to be able to refer to each stack so that I can change its color and add labels to the each stack as well as the total on the top. (of course no label at the base)

```py
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

Data = {'Labels':['A','B','C','D','E','F','F','G','H'],
       'Base':['0','1092','975','0','630','523','0','319','0'],
       'A':['546','208','266','487','172','53','261','102','159'],
       'B':['546','208','266','487','172','53','261','102','159']}
WF = pd.DataFrame(Data)
a = WF.columns.drop('Labels')
WF[a] = WF[a].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
colors = ["#FFFFFF", "#0076B6","#4099C9"]
a = WF.loc[:,['Base','A','B']].plot.bar(stacked=True, color = colors, 
width=0.8, figsize=(20,10))
a.set_facecolor('w')
a.set_xticklabels(WF['Labels'].to_list())
for p in a.patches[9:]:
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    a.text(x+width/2, 
            y+height/2, 
            '{:.0f}'.format(height), 
            horizontalalignment='center', 
            verticalalignment='center')
```

This gives me what I want but I can't color individual x bars, i.e. I need columns C, E, and F to be red.
[image]

But this code done with Bokeh achieves what I need.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.transform import stack, factor_cmap
import pandas as pd
#output_notebook()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Category": ['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9'],
    "Regime1_Value": [0, 841.77, 1140.52, 0, 674.25, 620.85, 0, 378.72, 0],
    "Regime1_State": ["D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"],
    "Regime2_Value": [546.12, 208.61, 93.11, 661.63, 172.70, 53.40, 453.53, 169.86, 265.67],
    "Regime2_State": ["C", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C"],
    "Regime3_Value": [295.65,183.24,0.00,478.89,293.57,0.00,185.32,72.27,113.04],
    "Regime3_State": ["B", "B", "E", "B", "E", "E", "B", "E", "B"]})

p = figure(x_range=['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9'],
          height=800, width=1200)
p.vbar_stack(["Regime1_Value", "Regime2_Value", "Regime3_Value"],
        x="Category",
        fill_color=[
            factor_cmap(state, palette=["#CC3333", "#4099C9", "#0076B6", 
"white", "#D65C5C"], factors=["A", "B", "C", "D","E"])
            for state in ["Regime1_State","Regime2_State", "Regime3_State"]],
        line_color="white",
        width=0.9,
        source=df,
            legend=[value(x) for x in ['','Tomato','Banana']])
p.background_fill_color = "white"
p.xgrid.visible = False
p.ygrid.visible = False

show(p)
```

So there the coloring is perfect, but I don't know how to add labels to each stack and a total label on the top. Also the base value which is the Regime1_value needs to be hidden.
[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.